# How do you pronounce "Weeoanwhisker"?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter universe, there's a barber shop near Diagon Alley called [Weeoanwhisker's Barber Shop](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Weeoanwhisker%27s_Barber_Shop).

How do you pronounce "Weeoanwhisker"?

Comment: Is there any better evidence that that's the name of the place, aside from the sign? I'm not convinced that it's not "*Weed and Whiskers"*

Answer (score 1):

Given it's London location, I'd opt for a British pronunciation, something very like /wiːəʊnwɪskəz/ --- "we own wiskaz". (While I personally disapprove of non-rhotacism, I get that Londoners and the English in general do insist upon it.)

Comment: It doesn't appear in the books. It only appears on a sign at the theme park

Comment: I suppose the downvotes are from staunchly anti-rhotic Brits! Also, thanks @Valorum for noting where the sign appears. While I concur that "Weed & Whiskers" would be a fantastic name, the sign pretty clearly says "Weeoanwhisker's".

Comment: Perhaps this in turn is a reference to the famous barber shop paradox. "We own whiskers" = "our own moustaches." Does a barber shave themself, if they shave everyone who does not do their own shaving?

Comment: My downvote is because this answer is pure supposition.

Comment: @Valorum -- While I appreciate that this kind of question skirts the borders of Opinionistan, I didn't pull that lot out of a hat, if that's what you mean by "supposition"! The IPA is solid (standard) UK pronunciation for those syllables. Given that this place is located in London, I think we can very securely conclude that some version of the English localect of that great city will have to inform our decisions as to how it's pronounced. This is specifically why I didn't choose some kind of American pronunciation!

Comment: Is the “o” ever pronounced as an “m” anywhere in Europe or the uk? Maybe something like “Weemanwhiskers”

Comment: @Deathlyhollows7 no, that would be very odd

Comment: As a London native myself, I would guess o-an was two syllables (wee owe an whiskers). Otherwise yes.

Comment: -1 for thinking rhoticity is something you can approve or disapprove of. You would be equally miffed if I decided I disapproved of that & many other Americanisms.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- Au contraire! I'm only miffed by Rightpondian antirhoticity. I highly approve of many of your other disapprovals of Americanisms.

Comment: I neither approve nor disapprove of rhoticity. It's not mine to approve, neither yours to disapprove.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- A pox on your ambivalence!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's supposed to be a pun on "we own whiskers" (whiskers being another word for beard). So just pronounce it like you would that.

JKR loves wordplay, and her other shops have vaguely pun-like names related to what they sell

- Gringotts: Bank. References ingots (bars of gold)
- Flourish and Blotts: Bookshop/stationers. Both things you can do when writing in ink (although hopefully the first, rather than the
  second!)
- Twilfitt And Tatting's: Robes. Twill is a material, clothes are being fitted    there, and tatting is lacemaking.
- Eeylops: Owl emporium. Could be from a combination of Eagle and Scops owl.
- Gambol and Japes. Joke shop. To gambol is to spring around happily, and jape is another word for joke.

so when other names were made up for the films or attractions whoever came up with them might have followed this convention.

This seems likely, as in the films/games/Wizarding World of Harry Potter we also have

- Slug and Jigger: Apothecary. Slug and jigger are both measurements of liquid (and horned slugs are a potion ingredient)
- Amanuensis Quills: An amanuensis is somebody who takes dictation, so would need a writing implement.
- Rosa Lee's Teabag: Café. Rosie Lee is cockney rhyming slang for tea.

Comment: JKR almost certainly didn't invent this store which only exists in Harry Potter Land.

Comment: Edited to add some more examples from non-books that follow the wordplay convention.